# QIcon display part of image , possible?

Tags: icons, paint, qt4.7

I wanted to use a single image for all of my button images , and when displaying icons , i wanted to display only desired range of that image , is it possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the icons from your 'sprite sheet' by reading it as a QImage and painting it into another QImage:

```
QIcon GetIcon(left, top, width, height) // or calculate these from an icon index or such
{
    QImage sprite, result;
    sprite = QImage(pathToSprite);
    result = QImage(resultingIconSize, theQImageFormat);
    QPainter painter(&result);
    painter.drawImage(0, 0, sprite, left, top, width, height);
    painter.end();

    return QIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(result));
}
```

By setting the [composition mode](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) you can even overlay several images with transparency.